# pandas: renaming column labels in multiindex df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multi-index

I have a df which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1|mm','2|lll'],['A|ljjh','B|ldjdj']])

       1|mm               2|lll          
     A|ljjh   B|ldjdj    A|ljjh   B|ldjdj
0  0.599202  0.093917  0.582809  0.683346
1  0.902717  0.343215  0.222960  0.238709
2  0.808473  0.290253  0.276607  0.775530
3  0.197891  0.505197  0.243890  0.011838
```

I would like to split the column labels for each level like so:

```
columnlabel.split("|")[0]
```

I'm not sure what the best method to do this? should I create a new list and assign that to df.columns or can I do it inplace??

expected output

```
     1                   2          
     A       B         A         B
0  0.599202  0.093917  0.582809  0.683346
1  0.902717  0.343215  0.222960  0.238709
2  0.808473  0.290253  0.276607  0.775530
3  0.197891  0.505197  0.243890  0.011838
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for parsing, create new list of `tuples` and last new `MultiIndex`[`from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
new_names = list(zip(df.columns.get_level_values(0).str.split('|').str[0],
                     df.columns.get_level_values(1).str.split('|').str[0]))
print (new_names)      
[('1', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'A'), ('2', 'B')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_names)
print (df)
          1                   2          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.400125  0.007743  0.423123  0.662878
1  0.787079  0.314668  0.798404  0.702267
2  0.451037  0.333846  0.030534  0.823515
3  0.135365  0.785421  0.777839  0.248622
```